# Polar decompotision in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there a built-in function in MATLAB that returns the polar decomposition of a square (real) matrix [image], e.g. returns two matrices [image] (unitary) and [image] (positive semi-definite symmetric/hermitian) such that [image] ?

Comment: Have you tried any of the FEX files?

Comment: No there isn't, but did you even try Google? This was the first result I got by searching `matrix polar decomposition MATLAB`: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48735-polar-decomposition.  Also this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20820-the-matrix-function-toolbox?focused=5102462&tab=function.

Comment: As you can read these solutions do not answer my question. Of course I did a search before and couldn't believe mathworks would not provide a convenient function for such an everyday problem.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware of any builtins, but you can use the singular value decomposition  `[U,S,V] = svd(A)` to get matrices `A = U*S*V'`. In order to get the polar decomposition you compute `B = U*V'` and `C = V*S*V'`. It is easy to see that `B` is unitary and `C` hermitian positive semidefinite by the properties of `U`, `S` and `V`.

Comment: That's pretty much how the second link I referred to computes it. +1.